# Android Studio Release debug

Tags: android, release-management

I made my android project successfully within any error.
But when I `Built/Release` it, I get this error:

```
        :app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug FAILED
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzqqzza.class
```

Comment: send the log cat with error details

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle. This might be an issue with dependencies

Comment: Show your `build.gradle`

Comment: Have you tried a Rebuild of the project in Release mode (Build -> Rebuild Project)?

Comment: Build/Successfull Thanku